# Error 'Dom7 is not defined' when starting Framework7 - Vue app with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, html-framework-7

I just follow the instructions in the [official website](https://framework7.io/vue/templates.html#framework7-vue-webpack-app-template): clone the repo, install node dependencies and run. But once I run the `npm run dev` command, when I open the app in the browser I get the following error:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Dom7 is not defined
>     at framework7.js:14213
>     at framework7.js:14317
>     at Object.<anonymous> (framework7.js:18375)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.9d7fa26….js:18538)
>     at n (bootstrap 4a945b6…:54)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (app.8e4833b….js:107)
>     at n (bootstrap 4a945b6…:54)
>     at window.webpackJsonp (bootstrap 4a945b6…:25)
>     at app.8e4833b….js:1
```

Can anyone help with this?

The most strange thing is that everything worked okey a few days ago.

Comment: same here. did you find a solution? thanks

Comment: @memical I've post a solution, not my favourite one, but will be enough till someone fix this problem with the new version

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be related with [the new Framework7 release from yesterday](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#framework7-v162---updated-on-may-29-2017), more accurately, the third item:

> **Dom7 Now it is used as a standalone library from
>   https://github.com/nolimits4web/Dom7**

So, I thought the problem would be fixed by installing it as a [standalone library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom7):

```
npm install dom7 --save
```

But that still doesn't fix it, so I figure some changes are still needed to configure it right.

So, finally, I've opted for the easiest solution, use the previous version of Framework7 until this problem is totally clarified by someone else.

So, please revert in your package.json to the **release version 1.6.0 of Framework7**.